# Unexpected call with google maps in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

I'm using google map API to design a "earthquake map". So far, so good.

The map displays nicely in Firefox and Chrome but raises a error in IE8:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 3 May 2013 08:13:44 UTC

Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 9
Char: 238
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/pt_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/12/10/main.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 650px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

var Parsed = [[]];
var txtFile; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    txtFile = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
txtFile.open("GET", "http://foo/f4/stats/nServsCodigoPostal.csv", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (txtFile.readyState === 4){  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
    if (txtFile.status === 200){  // Makes sure it's found the file.

        allText = txtFile.responseText; 
        Parsed = CSVToArray(allText, ";")
        }
    }
    function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){

        strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");
        var objPattern = new RegExp(
            (
                // Delimiters.
                "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

                // Quoted fields.
                "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

                // Standard fields.
                "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
            ),
            "gi"
            );
        var arrData = [[]];
        var arrMatches = null;
        while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){
            var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];
            if (
                strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
                (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
                ){
                arrData.push( [] );
            }
            if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){
                var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
                    new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
                    "\""
                    );
            } else {
                var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];
            }
            arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
        }
        return( arrData );
    }

    var locations = [
    ['Viana do Castelo', 41.6872711837914, -8.82476806640625, ],
    ['Braga', 41.54944320851238, -8.414154052734375, ],
    ['Porto', 41.15875373498798, -8.610706329345703, ],
    ['Aveiro', 40.63896734381723,-8.648300170898438, ],
    ['Vila Real', 41.30050773444147, -7.752227783203125, ],
    ['Bragança', 41.80535774441799, -6.760368347167969, ],
    ['Viseu', 40.64730356252251, -7.8936767578125, ],
    ['Guarda', 40.53258931069557, -7.25921630859375, ],
    ['Coimbra', 40.20195268954057, -8.433380126953125, ],
    ['Leiria', 39.7462660621837, -8.81103515625, ],
    ['Santarém', 39.774769485295465, -8.5693359375, ],
    ['Castelo Branco', 39.82013946676259, -7.505035400390625, ],
    ['Portalegre', 39.28860847419942, -7.42950439453125, ],
    ['Lisboa', 38.72891158257716, -9.139251708984375, ],
    ['Èvora', 38.56749535882734, -7.9046630859375, ],
    ['Setúbal', 38.5299046000139, -8.876953125, ],
    ['Beja', 38.01509916686995, -7.862606048583984, ],
    ['Faro', 37.017905231730914, -7.922515869140625, ]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i<Parsed.length; i++){
    var a = new String(Parsed[i][0]);
    Parsed[i][0] = a.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
        for(var j = 0; j<locations.length; j++){
        var b = new String(locations[j][0]);
        locations[j][0] = b.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
            if(Parsed[i][0]==locations[j][0]){
            locations[j][3] = ((0.07*Parsed[i][2])+4.875);
            }
        }
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -8.37),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for( var i = 0;  i < locations.length;  i++ ) {
    addMarker( locations[i] );
    }

    function addMarker( location ) {
        var lat = location[1], lng = location[2],
            magnitude = location[3], content = location[0];

        var options = {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
            map: map
        };

        if( magnitude < 5 ) {
            options.animation = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
        }
        else {
            options.icon = getCircle( magnitude );
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker( options );

        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent( content );
            infowindow.open( map, marker );
        });
    }

    function getCircle(magnitude) {
        return {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            fillColor: 'red',
            fillOpacity: .5,
        scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / Math.PI,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeWeight: .5
        };
    }
};
txtFile.send(null); 

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My source code is above. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Update1: [New Source code](http://pastebin.com/7wiebb4d) but same problem.

Update2: Run Firebug, no problem was found.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Your main problem is the trailing commas after the last element in each array, e.g.:

```
['Beja', 38.01509916686995, -7.862606048583984, ],
```

Do this instead:

```
['Beja', 38.01509916686995, -7.862606048583984 ],
```

This will always crash IE.  There are some other more minor problems with the code that JSLint will reveal.

Comment: You might want to move your JS into a function in the <head></head> of the document, and call it on window load

Comment: That's one idea. I started this way mainly because the way google examples are structured. I'm gone try using your approach with the "canvas" instead of "map".

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer just some info.
The problem may not be within your code there is an issue between IE8 and Google apps ( including Maps api).    Google ended support for IE8 this past November 15th http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33864

This simple example page from Google will crash IE8, it will load fine, press F5 and IE will crash. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple

Google did push out an update to Maps on April 29th enhancing some features,  which caused nightly failures in our lab, due to this issue.  I have not found a fix or workaround for it.

Do you need a ;  at the end of this:  Parsed = CSVToArray(allText, ";")  ?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me. After a dozen of ideas, I ended up with the following working(!) solution:

Before loading the content, destroy the object that the map is attached to.

e.g. if your map is set using:

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);`

use this code before doing the ajax request:

`$('#map-canvas').remove();`