# 'document' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

IE8 is giving me an error of 'document' is null or not an object.

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 3 May 2013 10:54:06 UTC


Message: 'document' is null or not an object
Line: 111
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://foo/f2/Teste.html
```

All browsers work except IE.

```
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 650px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ActiveXObject;
var Parsed = [[]];
var txtFile;
```

and,

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -8.37),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

The only thing i remember was the problem with .getElemntByID('') but it's correctly assigned to map.

What seems to be the problem?

Full code is here : [Source Code](http://pastebin.com/7wiebb4d)

Comment: `var ActiveXObject;` this line is not in the source but is in your sample... have you tried removing it? It doesn't seem to be related to the error however, but it will make some code below fail.

Comment: I think that was it! I tried to work the code as JSlint says and ended up initializing that variable. Although the problem now is back to the old one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354566/unexpected-call-with-google-maps-in-ie8 . Internet Explorer is a pain...

Answer (score 0):

you need to include excanvas.js in IE:  http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/downloads/list good luck and enjoy

This is written by Google and allows the Canvas to display in IE8 and lower

Comment: Noob question. How do i add this?

Update: Forget it...Readme file :)

Comment: Nop, canvas doesn't solve anything. I want a map, so i need to call: 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Correct, you need the excanvas to make the map show up you will include both.

Comment: but my map shows in IE if i don't include any markers (red circle), the standard appear just fine. Excanvas also deals with markers?

Comment: Modern browsers like Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera support the HTML5 canvas tag to allow 2D command-based drawing. ExplorerCanvas brings the same functionality to Internet Explorer. To use, web developers only need to include a single script tag in their existing web pages. So yes.